# Laravel groupBy Language

Tags: laravel-9

I have tables as I mentioned below. The pivot operations are complete, but what I want to do is to group the `Gallery` data. I want it to do it according to lang in the group

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('gallery_language', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignIdFor(Gallery::class)->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignIdFor(Language::class)->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Gallery Model
```

```
public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
    }
```

```
GalleryController
```

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $dataa = Language::groupBy('slug')->get();
       return response()->json($dataa);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but if you want group a specific gallery by language then use this:

```
$gallery = Gallery::find(1); /* select first gallery */
$dataa = $gallery->languages()->groupBy('slug')->get();
```

also you can first get all galleries then use the relation in a loop ( like foreach)

```
/* in controller: */
$galleries = Gallery::all();

/* in blade: */
@foreach ($galleries as $gallery)
$dataa = $gallery->languages()->groupBy('slug')->get();
@endforeach
```

if you want to access all data by group, you must join three tables, like this:

```
    $dataa = Gallery::join('gallery_languages','gallery_languages.gallery_id','galleries.id')
->join('languages','languages.id','gallery_languages.language.id')
->groupBy('gallery.id','languages.slug')->get();
```

You can first get datas and then group on laravel collection, it is more flexible for work with datas, but it is slower:

```
    $dataa = Gallery::join('gallery_languages','gallery_languages.gallery_id','galleries.id')
        ->join('languages','languages.id','gallery_languages.language.id')
        ->select('gallery.id as id','languages.slug as slug' ,'and more data that you want')
->get()->groupBy(['id','slug'])-all();
```

replace `'and more data that you want'` with columns that you need